# Adjusting layout for an imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I want to adjust the layout for an application.
First of all im new in android design.
I have made a linearlayout in a scrollview .
But when adjusting the layouts there are so many spaces coming between the images. i want to get rid of that.

The images should have the width equal to the phone's display. Height must be auto adjusted.

[image]

The xml code is listed below.
Comment me if the question is not clear.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/sldr4" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/sldr4" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [adjustViewBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds) XML attribute:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```